# How to catch exceptions which occur inside asynchronous methods? (Windows Store app, PPL)

Tags: asynchronous, c++11, exception, windows-store-apps, ppl

I am trying to catch exception from OnlineIdAuthenticator::AuthenticateUserAsync method, which occurs when there is no internet connection for example.

I've found [some info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781020.aspx) about this topic, but it didn't really help me.

Here is the code which demonstrates the way that I tried to process errors:

```
auto auth = ref new OnlineIdAuthenticator ();
auto request = ref new OnlineIdServiceTicketRequest ("wl.signin wl.basic wl.skydrive_update", "DELEGATION");
auto request_vec = ref new Vector <OnlineIdServiceTicketRequest ^> ();
request_vec->Append (request);

create_task (auth->AuthenticateUserAsync (request_vec, CredentialPromptType::RetypeCredentials))
.then ([] (UserIdentity ^ident)
{
    try
    {
        auto ticket = ident->Tickets->GetAt (0);
        token = std::wstring (ticket->Value->Data ());
    }
    catch (const concurrency::task_canceled &)
    {
        int _break_point_here = 0;
    }
    catch (const std::exception &)
    {
        int _break_point_here = 0;
    }
    catch (Platform::Exception ^ex)
    {
        int _break_point_here = 0;
    }
});
```

But no one from these catches doesn't work when AuthenticateUserAsync method fails. 
Any help, please. What is the right way to catch exceptions from asynchronous method?

Comment: I understand that this code sample is a bit stupid because try block doesn't wrap AuthenticateUserAsync call. But I just don't understand how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got answer [here](https://casablanca.codeplex.com/discussions/444248). Question is closed.